# Computer can connect to web and domain in one location, but not another [wired]

Tags: networking

i have an xp computer im trying to hook up in a new location. i connected it originally in location A, and i was able to connect to the domain and web without issue. when i moved that computer into location B and it shows that it is connected, but i cannot ping, join the domain, or browse the web. the pc that was connected there before had no connection issues, and there is a VoIP phone in the room running off the connection fine. i also brought another laptop down to location B and it connected without issue. when i bring the computer that is having the issue back up to location A, it connects fine as well. IP configuration is set to automatic.

im very stumped at this point, thank you for any advice!

Comment: In Location B: Does it get a link light?  Does it actually get an IP address from DHCP?  Have you tried Safe Mode (w/ Networking)?

Comment: it did get a link light and an ip. we actually managed to resolve the issue. seems to have been something with our switch. power cycled the switch and its now up and running. thank you!

Comment: Sounds like the question could be answered then with the troubleshooting performed for future searchres